# Multiple addEventListeners in js file, only one works

Tags: javascript, html

So I'm playing around with HTML and JS, and I have two web pages, each with their own addEventListener I need to work when a user submits a form from those pages.  However, only the eventlistener for my Log In page is working - the one for my Reset Password page doesn't.  I've tried swapping their order in the JS file, and then my Reset Password one works, and my Log In doesn't.  Is it possible to have many addEventListeners in one JS file all work appropriately when needed?

Below is the code:

**Log In In Page HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Log In</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css">
</head>
<body id="formBodyBG">
<header>    
    <div>
        <div id="navMenu">
          <ul>
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="index.html" class="navLink home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="createAccount">
              <a href="createAccount.html" class="navLink createAccountButton">Create Account</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
<section class="mainBody">
    <div class="leftSide"></div>
    <div class="mainForm">
            <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:12px; font-size:32px">Welcome Back!</h1>
            <h5 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:25px">Log in to review, analyze past trends, or import new data.</h5>
            <form class="form" id="loginForm" action="dashboard.html" method="GET">
                <div class="mainFormDesign">
                    <label>Username</label>
                    <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="input"><br>
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error message</small><br><br>
                </div>
                <div class="mainFormDesign">
                    <div style="width: 50%; float:left">
                        <label>Password</label>
                    </div>
                    <div style="width: 50%; float:right">
                        <label><a href="resetPassword.html" class="label">Forgot Password?</a></label>
                    </div>
                    <input id="password" type="password" name="password" class="input"><br>
                    <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                    <small>Error message</small><br><br>
                </div>
                <button class="loginButton" id="loginSubmit">Log In</button>
                <br><br><hr>
                <h5 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:35px;" class="secondCreateAccountLink">New to StigTracker? <a href="createAccount.html" class="accountLink">Create an account.</a></h5>
            </form>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide"></div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pages/code.js"></script>
```

**Reset Password Page HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Reset Password</title>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body id="formBodyBG">
<header>    
    <div>
        <div id="navMenu">
          <ul>
            <li class="logo">
                <a href="index.html" class="navLink home">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="createAccount">
              <a href="createAccount.html" class="navLink createAccountButton">Create Account</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
</header>
<section class="mainBody">
    <div class="leftSide"></div>
    <div class="mainForm">
        <h1 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:12px; font-size:32px">Reset Your Password</h1>
        <h5 style="text-align:center; margin-bottom:25px">Enter a valid email to receive instructions on how to reset your password.</h5>
        <form class="form" id="resetForm" action="resetSuccess.html" method="GET">
            <div class="mainFormDesign">
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="email" id="email" name="email" class="input"><br>
                <i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i>
                <small>Error message</small><br><br>
            </div>
            <button class="loginButton" id="resetSubmit">Reset Password</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="rightSide"></div>
</section>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/pages/code.js"></script>
```

**JS:**

```
const username = document.getElementById('username')
const password = document.getElementById('password')
const email = document.getElementById('email')
const loginForm = document.getElementById('loginForm')
const resetForm = document.getElementById('resetForm')

loginForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (username.value === '' || username.value == null) {
        setErrorFor(username,'Username cannot be blank.')
    }
    else if (username.value !== 'testuser') {
        setErrorFor(username,'Username is not valid.')
    }
    else {
        setSuccessFor(username)
    }

    if (password.value === '' || password.value == null) {
        setErrorFor(password,'Password cannot be blank.')
    }
    else if (password.value !== '123456') {
        setErrorFor(password,'Password is not valid.')
    }
    else {
        setSuccessFor(password)
    }

    if (username.value === 'testuser' & password.value === '123456') {
        window.location.href = "index.html";
    }
})

resetForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    if (email.value === '' || email.value == null) {
        setErrorFor(email,'Email cannot be blank.')
    }
    else if (email.value !== 'edward.champa@us.af.mil') {
        setErrorFor(email,'Email is not valid.')
    }
    else {
        setSuccessFor(email)
    }

    if(!isEmail(email.value)) {
        setErrorFor(email,'Email is not valid.')
    }
    else {
        window.location.href = "index.html"; 
    }
})

function setErrorFor(input, message) {
    const mainFormDesign = input.parentElement;
    const small = mainFormDesign.querySelector('small');

    small.innerText = message;

    mainFormDesign.className = 'mainFormDesign error';
}

function setSuccessFor(input) {
    const mainFormDesign = input.parentElement;

    mainFormDesign.className = 'mainFormDesign success';
}
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console?

Comment: One weird thing stood out (not technically an issue), and one bigger issue.  The weird thing is that you give both of your form's actions.  But in both of your submit handlers you cancel the form submits and then redirect to a different page than the action of your form.  So that's weird.  The bigger issue though is that you are performing authentication in the client, which is a major security no no.  You might as well not have a login at all if you implement authentication that way.

Comment: @Charles - Unfortunately not that I can see, writing this in visual studio code.  I'm kind of a noob, is there a way to compile and see that in vsc?

Comment: @Taplar - Also, I'm just testing out CSS with the JS, not planning on authenticating on the client.

Comment: So you wrote up this entire example of an issue, just to show an issue with js changing css?  I don't understand...

Comment: I think you might have an error on the resetform page since loginform doesnt exist, this stops the javascript from completing, the other way around it will probably trow an error but work for the login part.. check the console indeed.. open the html in browser and press F12

Comment: ^^^ good catch, getElementById on a non-match returns null.  null.addEventListener is going to be a null pointer exception

Comment: @Sanavi Could you add a live demo here?

Comment: @Rmaxx That's what I was thinking. The developer console in the browser should report the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have an error on the resetform page since loginform doesn't exist, this stops the javascript from completing, the other way around it will probably throw an error, but work for the login part.. check the console indeed.. open the html in browser and press F12

Solution: only add the eventlistener is the element !== null

```
if ((typeof loginForm === 'undefined') || (loginForm !== null)){
   loginForm.addEventListener......
}
```

Comment: That worked nicely.  I did end up just creating functions for each event and adding them as an on click, so either way works.